# What is the difference betweeen hook_validate and case 'validate' in hook_nodeapi

Tags: 6, hooks

I am bit confused about `hook_validate()` and case 'validate' in `hook_nodeapi()`. Both do  validate a node.

Could anyone clear me the difference with a simple example that even a beginner can understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hook_validate` is used inside a module that creates a node type of its own, and is used along with the form used to create the node to validate that all the information required has been entered.

For example, let's say you created a node type with a specific field in it of "area" and you wanted to make sure it was of the format city-state.  You would do it in here.

`hook_nodeapi` with `op=validate` is used to validate any nodes that are being edited but not created by the module in question.

For example, let's say you wanted to make sure a description field in a node with that field had more than 1000 characters.  You would do it with `nodeapi`/`validate`.

Carefully read [`hook_validate`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--node.php/function/hook_validate/6) and [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) for more information or clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is the following:

**hook_validate:** when you create a new content-type programmatically you can use a certain number of hooks for define a how will be behave your new content-type, you can see these hooks in the [developer hooks section of Drupal site](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--node.php/6), between that hooks exists hook_validate for apply a validation for your new content-type.

**validate in hook_nodeapi:** with this, you can add any validation for a node for any content type .